# Regex of statement does not contain in sentence

Tags: java, regex

```
com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.BROUDNHDJDJDNXJSNZKSNSJH

com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.int.BROUDNHDJDJDNXJSNZKSNSJH
```

**Regex** : `com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.*.`

The above regex is selecting both the expression, I want to select only first pattern without int .

select     com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.BROUDNHDJDJDNXJSNZKSNSJH

and should not select com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.int.BROUDNHDJDJDNXJSNZKSNSJH
as it has int

Comment: The dot in regex match any character, including the dot. Replace the end of your regex with equipment\.[^.]* or equipment\.\w*  You should also put slashes in front of other dots in your regex

Comment: not match only if the `int` package is present, or not if any other package(s) is present? what should happen with e.g. `com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.ext.BROUDNHDJDJDNXJSNZKSNSJH`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead assertion to cover your requirement:

```
String input = "com.sap.dsc.ac.v1.equipment.BROUDNHDJDJDNXJSNZKSNSJH";
if (input.matches("com\\.sap\\.dsc\\.ac\\.v1\\.equipment\\.(?!int\\.).*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

The `(?!int\\.)` terms tells the regex engine to look ahead at that point in the package name and make sure that `int.` does not follow.  If so, in then accepts anything else which might follow as being a valid match.

Answer (score 0):

'.' symbol in regexp means one any symbol, if you want to use '.' as a char - you need to escape them

```
com\.sap\.dsc\.ac\.v1\.equipment\..*\..*
```

'\.' - is a dot char in the line

'.*' - any numbers of any chars

But the regexp above will be true for any lines which contain any numbers of chars between the dots before the last word. If you want to match only lines, which contains 'int' - just replace first '.*' to 'int'

```
com\.sap\.dsc\.ac\.v1\.equipment\.int\..*
```

And now if you want that the part after '.int.' doesn't contain dot symbol - add excepting '.':

```
com\.sap\.dsc\.ac\.v1\.equipment\.int\.[^.]*
```